# How to return complex (dict) value from Kubernetes Helm function?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want to return a complex value (dict) from a Helm function, so that I can do further processing in the template or other functions.

I have defined this function:

```
{{- define "return-dict-function" -}}
key1: value1
key2: value2
{{- end -}}
```

And I can output the function value in my template:

```
{{ include "return-dict-function" . | nindent 2 }}
```

But how can I do further processing with the data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several solutions to return complex values and do further processing:

**1) function returns plain yaml**

Take the example function `return-dict-function` from the question.
If you use `fromYaml` you'll get a `dict`:

```
{{ $dict := include "return-dict-function" . | fromYaml }}
type: {{ $dict | typeOf }}
{{- range $key, $value := $dict }}
simple-function-{{ $key }} : processed-value-{{ $value }}
{{- end -}}
```

Output:

```
type: map[string]interface {}
simple-function-key1 : processed-value-value1
simple-function-key2 : processed-value-value2
```

**2) function needs to return dict**

**a) serialize to json**

If you have a dict which should be returned you can serialize the dict with `toJson`

```
{{- define "return-dict-function-json" -}}
{{- $result := dict "key1" "value1" "key2" "value2" }}
{{- $result | toJson  -}}
{{- end -}}
```

Later you will deserialize with `fromJson`

```
{{ $dict := include "return-dict-function-json" . | fromJson }}
{{- range $key, $value := $dict }}
json-function-{{ $key }} : processed-value-{{ $value }}
{{- end -}}
```

**b) serialize to yaml**

You can also serialize the dict with `toYaml`

```
{{- define "return-dict-function-yaml" -}}
{{- $result := dict "key1" "value1" "key2" "value2" }}
{{- $result | toYaml  -}}
{{- end -}}
```

Then you need to deserialize with `fromYaml`

```
{{ $dict := include "return-dict-function-yaml" . | fromYaml }}
{{- range $key, $value := $dict }}
yaml-function-{{ $key }} : processed-value-{{ $value }}
{{- end -}}
```

**Notes and further readings**

- Of course this also works with nested values
- [Advanced Helm Templating](https://blog.flant.com/advanced-helm-templating/)
- [Helm Docs](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/)